# How can I benchmark my website with SPDY support?

Tags: apache-2.2, benchmark, spdy

I'm currently running a lot of configuration benchmarks on my server using **siege**,
and I would like to try the SPDY protocol (with mod_spdy for Apache) - but siege use HTTP.

Do you know any tool which would allow me to compare my website performance in a high concurrency environment with and without SPDY?

Comment: use nginx for spdy!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The performance of your SPDY setup will obviously depend on the implementation of the stack and you should know the processing cost vs. a 'regular' HTTP or HTTPS session, but.. Keep in mind that that the primary point of SPDY is to reduce the latency and overhead of rendering a typical webpage (as seen by your visitors), not to optimize your server-side response time.

More specifically: if you want to benchmark SPDY, siege/ab and friends are not representative. All of these tools generate load against a single URI and hammer it. This is a useful tactic to stress test your server, but it is far from testing the benefits of SPDY. To test SPDY, you want a tool (browser, most likely), which will download the page, *and* request all the subresources on the page, allowing you to reuse the SPDY connection.

We recently ran some benchmarks using Chrome for Android, and you can see the setup here: https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/spdy-for-mobile

Finally. If you do need a command line client to test SPDY, checkout [spdylay](https://github.com/tatsuhiro-t/spdylay). It ships with `spdycat` which will allow you to make curl-like requests against your server. It's not a benchmarking tool, but it'll get you started.

Comment: I see you are also using spdy for http besides https? I can't see it enabled on http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_University

Answer (score 2):

Jetty provides an asynchronous pure [Java SPDY client](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/SPDY) that you can use to simulate browsers requests, measure latencies, etc.

Along with that, Jetty provides also an asynchronous [HTTP client](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/HttpClient), so you can compare the performances of your website in the two cases.